# Use existing e4 Part in legacy IEditorPart

Tags: e4

I have an implementation for a part in native e4.
The part's UI shall now also be shown within a `MultiPageEditorPart` which seems to enforce e3 style editors.

What would be the recommended approach for this? As far as I can tell, I could access all the menus and binding contexts from the `EModelService` and then manually process them in the e3 legacy part. Is this a good way to handle this?

Comment: `MultiPageEditorPart` is really just wrapping a `CTabFolder` control, if you want to stick to pure e4 it might just be simpler to just use a CTabFolder.

Comment: @greg-449: another page of the `MultiPageEditorPart` will be an XtextEditor (which implements the legacy e3 editor). I guess it is not possible to integrate it to an e4 part without any problems?

Comment: If  you have something that expects to be in 3.x compatibily mode it will be a lot of work to run in pure e4.